# How do I get the Tomcat 7 Embedded container to use another port?

Tags: gradle, jboss-arquillian

I have Arquillian setup in Gradle to spin up a REST server and run some tests against a REST client. Everything works fine, except for the fact that the server hosting the CI already uses port 8080.

I have added the following settings to my build.gradle file

```
arquillian {
  containers {
    tomcat {
      version = '7'
      config = ['bindHttpPort': 18080]
      type = 'embedded'
    }
  }
}
```

But it has no effect. How can I change the port used by the embedded tomcat 7 container?

**EDIT**

There is a workaround, which is to have the following in a file called arquillian.xml. Still, it would be nice to have the option of defining the port in the build.gradle file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="tomcat" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <!-- We need to change the port from the default of 8080 because 8080 is quite commonly not available -->
            <property name="bindHttpPort">18080</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```